# hey new yorkers, who's recording occupy wallstreet?

Tags: field-recording, new, york

over 15000 people there right now, and they've been doing things like the "human microphone" which seem really cool.

[youtube]JCjs7YTxcVU[/youtube]

who's rolling on this?  Wanna trade?  :)

---

edit:

looks like someone in portland got a bunch of good stuff:
http://www.organiccitysounds.com/2011/10/portland-soundscape-occupied/
[soundcloud]organic-city-sounds/portland-portrait-occupied[/soundcloud]

There is an occupy Dallas movement, but its not anywhere near the scale of what's happening in NY.  I'm going to see it this weekend and try to get some good stuff though.

you guys that are heading to NY, don't forget to dive into the protests and record some chants!  I have a feeling there will be a fair amount of demonstration media being developed in the coming months that will need good sounds.  ;)

---

edit 2:

I went out yesterday and got a mountain of good stuff.  fully 45 minutes of chants and cheers.

here's a taste and a blog post.

[soundcloud]rcoronado/occupy-dallas-march-comp[/soundcloud]

http://thesoundmyheadmakes.blogspot.com/2011/10/recording-of-occupy-dallas.html

Comment: I would totally be up for some sound trades too with anyone capturing this

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping they're still there when I go up to AES in two weeks. Hoping for an awesome AES SSD meetup + crowd recording excursion. ;)

Comment: i'd be up for that.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to get to Occupy Philly, might be able to get some recordings if I can carry my gear on the bus.

Answer (score 0):

gonna try and snatch occupy nola if i can borrow a recorder from a buddy of mine, My recorder has bit the dust as of late.

Answer (score 0):

Was planning to get there all week, but life got in the way. If it's still active next week I'll do my best to get over there and get some stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Going to NYC to record over the next couple of days. I hope to hit up wall street on thursday or friday.

Answer (score 0):

I got out to Occupy Times Square and grabbed some stuff. Here's a link to one of the better recordings, all of which come from my little Zoom H4N.

[Crowd Protest Banks Got Bailed Out Times Square](http://soundcloud.com/rogermiddenway/crowd-protest-banks-got-bailed) by [Roger Middenway](http://soundcloud.com/rogermiddenway)

I'm hoping to get them cut and labeled next week. Just give me a shout if you want them.

Comment: I'd love to to grab a copy :)  Happy to make a sound trade too.

Comment: ditto.  I have that chant, and its funny how much the dallas and NY chants sound alike.  :)